# Assignment operator with reference members

Tags: c++, reference

Is this a valid way to create an assignment operator with members that are references?

```
#include <new>

struct A
{
    int &ref;
    A(int &Ref) : ref(Ref) { }
    A(const A &second) : ref(second.ref) { }
    A &operator =(const A &second)
    {
        if(this == &second)
            return *this;
        this->~A();
        new(this) A(second);
        return *this;
    }
}
```

It seems to compile and run fine, but with c++ tendency to surface undefined behavior when least expected, and all the people that say its impossible, I think there is some gotcha I missed. Did I miss anything?

Comment: By the way, the arguments to `operator=` and the copy constructor should be const references.

Comment: Correctness may be limited to standard layout types, since with virtuals `this` need not be a pointer to the beginning of the memory block.

Comment: If you need to do this I'd suggest rethinking using references.

Comment: References can not be reseated.  If you need to reseat one, then a reference was not the correct type in the first place.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's syntactically correct.  If the placement new throws, however, you
end up with an object you can't destruct.  Not to mention the disaster
if someone derives from your class.  Just don't do it.

The solution is simple: if the class needs to support assignment, don't
use any reference members.  I have a lot of classes which take reference
arguments, but store them as pointers, just so the class can support
assignment.  Something like:

```
struct A
{
    int* myRef;
    A( int& ref ) : myRef( &ref ) {}
    // ...
};
```

Comment: I like this -- straightforward solution!

Answer (score 10):

Another solution is to use the reference_wrapper class ( in functional header ) :

```
struct A
{
    A(int& a) : a_(a) {}
    A(const A& a) : a_(a.a_) {}

    A& operator=(const A& a)
    {
        a_ = a.a_;
        return *this;
    }

    void inc() const
    {
        ++a_;
    }

    std::reference_wrapper<int>a_;

};
```

Comment: With an assignment expression `a = b;` when `a` has type `reference_wrapper<T>`, it seems that if `b` has type (convertible to?) `reference_wrapper<T>`, this will *reseat* `a` to refer to `b`, but if not, and if `b` has type (convertible to?) `T`, the `T` object referenced by `a` will be assigned the value `b`.  Is this true?  If so, it seems to introduce some subtleties for implementing function templates that perform `a = b;` where we don't know the concrete types, but only that `b`'s type is implicitly convertible to `a`'s.

Answer (score 4):

What you do its technically correct as far as I know, but it generates trouble. For instance, consider what happens with a derived class from `A`, since its assignment operator generates a new object (slicing). Can't you just turn the reference into a pointer within your class?

Besides that, copy constructors and assignment operators usually take its argument by `const&`.

Comment: How does this generate trouble?

Answer (score 1):

What you do is correct, but it is not very exception safe way of writing an copy assignment operator. Also, You should consider using a pointer member rather than an reference member.

You should implement it using the **[Copy and Swap Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)**. It has atleast 3 advantages over your implementation.

Comment: But then how to swap the references?

Comment: @ChristianRau:You would be implementing your own `swap` function anyways.

Comment: Yes, and this probably needs to swap the references.

Comment: Specifically, `swap` will require destroying `A` and then calling placement new, just like this does.  Copy-and-swap depends on there being a nothrow swap implementation available, and this type does not have one.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: It saves you the self assignment check.