# How do reference_wrapper and std::ref work?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand how std::ref works.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <class C>
void func(C c){
    c += 1;
}

int main(){
    int x{3};
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    func(x);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    func(std::ref(x));
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

Output : 3 3 4
```

In the code above, I think the template parameter `C` for the third function call is instantiated as `std::reference_wrapper<int>`.
While reading [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper),
I noticed there is no `+=` operator in `std::reference_wrapper<int>`.
Then, how is `c += 1;` valid?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> how is `c += 1;` valid?

Because `reference_wrapper<int>` is implicitly convertible to `int&` via its conversion operator; and implicit conversions are considered for operands if there is no suitable overload for the operand type itself.

Comment: @Sungmin: Indeed, `c` itself can't change type; but `+=` is applied to the result of `c.operator int&()` which will be a reference to target of the `reference_wrapper`.

Comment: Note this magic only works for operators.  For example, if `x` were of class type and had a method `x.foo()`, and you tried to wrap a reference to `x` in a `reference_wrapper` `rx`, you could not just say `rx.foo()`. You would have to say `rx.get().foo()`, which is about as ugly as just using a pointer `px->foo`.  So unfortunately `std::reference_wrapper` is not a magical do-all wrapper for references (which is what a lot of people hope to use it for, e.g. [for copying objects with reference members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906127/assignment-operator-with-reference-members)).

Answer (score 12):

`std::reference_wrapper<T>` has a [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get) to `T&`. This means that std::reference_wrapper can be implicitly converted to `int&` in your example.

Comment: The two answers were uploaded almost the same time. But Mike Seymour's answer is a little bit faster. Apart from that, I cannot determine which one to pick. Sorry for that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Sungmin You are welcome. I think Seymour's answer is better anyway: he explains about the operators overloads and operands, which I failed to do.